# Add whatsapp share button to php plugin

Tags: wordpress, share, whatsapp

I would like to add a share button to a plugin I already installed on wordpress.
I looked for the action to do that, found a bunch of solution but none of them seem to work.

```
<?php if ( in_array( 'vk', $share_buttons, true ) ) : ?>
    <button class="wq-share-vk wq_shareVK" data-url="<?php echo esc_url( $share_url ); ?>"><i class="sprite sprite-vk"></i><span><?php esc_html_e( 'VK', 'wp-quiz-pro' ); ?></span></button>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is the code to share with vk. what would be the best solution to share with whatsapp. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -2):

fistful check your data var_dump()